# Prove that vector norm $1$ is indeed a norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$ .

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Prove that $‖·‖_1$ is indeed a norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$.  You are allowed to assume the triangle inequality for the absolute value function, that is,$|a+b|≤|a|+|b|$ .

I know that vector norm $1$ is the sum of all elements in the vector but I am not how to start this proof. And what does this have anything to do with triangle inequality?

Comment: What are the requirements to call something a norm? Take them one by one and check that $\|{}\cdot{}\|_1$ fulfills them.

Comment: @Arthur Requirements to call something a norm are Positive definiteness, Scalar homogeneity, and Triangle Inequality. Triangle Inequality is already given in the question to be assumed. Positive definiteness says that norm of x equals 0 iff x = 0. But I am not given any info about the x. So how would I continue from here?

Comment: Triangle inequality of _numbers_ is given. You have to use that to prove triangle inequality for vectors. Also, obviously you're not given any info about $x$, as the statements should be true for _all_ vectors $x$ in your vector space.

Comment: Part of the problem is that what you "know", "that vector norm 1
is the sum of all elements in the vector" is incorrect!  $||v||_1$ is the sum of the **absolute values** of the element of the vector.  With your idea, for example, the "norm" of the non-zero vector, <1, -1> would be 1+ (-1)= 0, violating one of the requirements of a norm, that the norm of a non-zero vector be positive.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since $\lVert x\rVert_1\ge 0$ prove the following

$$\lVert x\rVert_1 = 0\iff x = 0$$

and

$$\lVert a+b\rVert_1\leq \lVert a\rVert_1+\lVert b\rVert_1$$

using

$$\lVert u\rVert_1=\sum_{i}|u_i|$$